# Trying to place expandable list view and 4 text box inside scroll view

Tags: android, scrollview, expandablelistview

Hi I am creating an application that contains two expandable list view and four other text views. My problem is whenever expandable list view is expanded other views are going down and became invisible. So i tried to put them in scroll view but it result is worst. So I do some surfing and find out an example in http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/expandable-listview-inside-scrollview/ , but it is also failed. I want all the views in Scroll view not only expandable list view. Here is my xml code in working condition without scroll view. Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#00BCD4">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/storeExpandableListView"
            android:childIndicator="@null"
            android:groupIndicator="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="-1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/nav_drawer">
        </ExpandableListView>

        <ExpandableListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/categoryExpandableListView"
            android:groupIndicator="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="-1dp"
            android:childIndicator="@null"
            android:background="@drawable/nav_drawer"
            android:layout_below="@+id/storeExpandableListView">
        </ExpandableListView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="338dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/reportTextView"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:text="@string/report"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/categoryExpandableListView"
            android:background="@drawable/nav_drawer"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="338dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/settingsTextView"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:text="@string/settings"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/reportTextView"
            android:background="@drawable/nav_drawer"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="338dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/aboutTextView"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:text="@string/about"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/settingsTextView"
            android:background="@drawable/nav_drawer"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="338dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/helpTextView"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:text="@string/help"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/aboutTextView"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="338dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spendidlyTextView"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="SPENDIDLY ("
            android:textColor="#00ABC1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/helpTextView"
            android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="georgia"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/versionTextView"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:textColor="#00ABC1"
            android:fontFamily="georgia"
            android:layout_marginStart="103dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/spendidlyTextView"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spendidlyTextView"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="338dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/closeBraceTextView"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:text=")"
            android:textColor="#00ABC1"
            android:fontFamily="georgia"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spendidlyTextView"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/versionTextView" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Note i already tried using setListViewHeight() method which is suggested in one of stackoverflow post

Comment: can you post the logcat error? @Karthik

Comment: i didn't mention about any errors.Please once again read my question. @Sushrita

Answer (score 0):

Well this of all I'd discourage from creating a layout with two expandable view's inside. That's the wrong thing to do, you should use one instead. The expandable view is not a "cheap" view, it uses a lot of resources, and if you were to add two of them into one view, they would not be smooth.